# Create symlinks with wildcard

Tags: linux, centos, symlink

I'd like to create a symlink with a wildcard :

```
ln -s jetty_server01.file jetty_*.file
```

So all requests to a file named `jetty_*.file` will link to target `jetty_server01.file`, in the same directory.

Is that possible?

Using CentOS 7.

Comment: while this can be answered quickly, I **bet** you would benefit from asking a new question describing why you need this, and whether there is a way around the problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: What form are the "requests"? Do you mean `cat jetty_foo.file` should show the contents of "jetty_server01.file"? Or is there some application involved here?

Comment: There's an application involved, requesting a temporary file (that doesn't exist) with a random part in its name (jetty_tuv2b.file, jetty_x893j.file, etc) and I wanted to create a link from existing reference file jetty_server01.file.

Comment: It's not possible with a symlink, but it is possible with a [FUSE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/FUSE) filesystem. I don't know of an existing, maintained filesystem that supports this. It's probably doable in a heavyweight way with a web server + davfs2.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not how file systems work. A file system stores *existing* file names, not *potential* file names.

"`*`" meaning "wildcard" is a feature of your shell when completing filenames by matching all existing file names in a directory against the pattern you specified. That does not happen when you open a file in a program.

If you want something like this, you would have to implement your own file system, or create a link for every actual potential file name.

Comment: I don't think this answer is good.  While it is acceptable to answer "no this can't be done" on some questions, OPs request can be done with a pretty simple loop and they aren't specifying how it needs to be done just what they want and how they think it would be done.

Comment: @jesse_b sorry, it really cannot be done. What OP requests is "So all requests to a file name `jetty_*.file` will link to…"; and that's plain not how file systems work, as you can only create links with actual names, not such that *mean* "wildcard" (see my answer).

Comment: That's what I expected as answer. Actually, I have a process requesting files "jetty_*.file" (ex: jetty_tvu4b.file), "*" part is random and temporary. I have a reference file in this same directory and wanted that my process follow a link to it.

Comment: Maybe but I think you are being hung up on verbiage and not the actual goal.  I could be wrong but it sounds like OP just wants to link all existing files to a single file which would just be something like `for f in ./jetty_*.file; do ln -s jetty_server01.file "$f"; done`

Comment: @jesse_b see tonio's comment above

Comment: Still can be done, just need something to monitor all changes to that directory and automatically link any new files created in it.  Almost anything is possible.

Comment: @jesse_b no, that also doesn't work - as tonio says they have a process *requesting* a file that did not exist before. You can't monitor for a change when there's no change.

Comment: I don't see the part where it says did not exist before.

Comment: Right and sorry for not saying it, but file did not exist and will never exist, that's why I was asking about a link with a wildcard

Comment: @tonio94 this is what's known as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask a new question, explain what your final objective is and then ask how to get it. Your process might be able to use wildcards, or you can have another process that first checks the actual file name and then creates a symlink, there are loads of options. But we need to know what your actual end objective is in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeees..., you can make a symlink with an asterisk in the name.

The command you gave would do just that if you quote the second filename (the one with the asterisk).

```
$ ln -s jetty_server01.file 'jetty_*.file'
$ ls -l jetty_\*.file 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 19 Jan 12 19:56 jetty_*.file -> jetty_server01.file
```

However, that's perhaps not very useful... You'll have to quote the filename every time you use it, since just using `jetty_*.file` in the shell would expand to all matching filenames, including both `jetty_*.file` and `jetty_server01.file`:

```
$ ls jetty_*.file
jetty_server01.file  jetty_*.file@
```

A file of the exact name existing doesn't stop the glob from matching others.

If you want a link to e.g. the latest of the set of files, it might be easier and less confusing to name it something like `jetty_current.file` or whatever. You'll have to update the link manually, of course.

(Other programs than the shell probably don't expand globs, so you might be able to use `jetty_*.file` in configuration files or such. But that might also be a bit confusing.)